# Prevent Form from Submitting if there are Errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Before I get into the problem details, I still need to tell you about this form I am creating. I have a Registration form and once the user submits the form by clicking the Submit button, it will NOT go directly to a Successfully Registered page. The user will be seeing a Confirmation page prior to that. In this page, the user will see all the data he inputted for him to review. Below it are the Confirm button and the Return button (if user still likes/needs to edit his details, it will then show the form for him to edit once this button is clicked). But here's the thing, the Registration form page and the Confirmation page are in just the same page. What I did is that when the user submits the form, it will hide some elements including the Submit button and then just show the details he inputted. When the user clicks the Return button on the Confirmation page, it will just then show again the hidden fields so the user can edit his details.

What I did in preventing the form from submitting when there are errors is that I disabled the submit button. But it is not working. I am using bootstrap for my form so when there are errors, the input fields' borders would turn red and would obtain a class `has-error`. Here's what I did:

```
$("td .form-group").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('has-error') == true) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
    } else { 
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

But again, it is not working. I also googled some jQueries like the `.valid()` and `.validate()` functions but I'm not really sure about it and also didn't work for me.

I also did this code where the Submit button should disable when required fields are still empty. And it is perfectly working:

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
$('input[id^="account"]').keyup(function() {
    if(($('#profile-company_name').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-mail_address').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-confirmemail').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-login_name').val().length !=0) && (($('#account-password').val().length !=0)) && ($('#account-confirmpassword').val().length !=0)) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

I hope you understand my problem. I will make it clearer if this confuses you.

Comment: return `false` if validation fails.

Comment: thanks for your response. do you have like, a code snippet?

Comment: can I know the version of the jquery and bootstrap that you are using...

Comment: @EtheleneLaverne an example https://jsfiddle.net/mLLbke4y/

Comment: @DivakarGujjala I can't really tell, it is not shown when I viewed the page source or inspected element since we are just used composer in installing them. So I think it's the latest versions.

Comment: @TintuCRaju thanks, but I need the Submit button to disable when there are field errors.

Comment: You can use buttons instead of submit buttons... Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/sLs6snL3/

Comment: @DivakarGujjala yes, by the way, I am already using buttons, not the `input` with `type='submit'`

Comment: can you use input type='button' instead other wise <button type="button">

Comment: @DivakarGujjala I just did now, still not working.

Comment: Can you refer the link https://jsfiddle.net/sLs6snL3/1/. I have changed input to button. Can you please validate the form with jquery instead of bootstrap at first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102201/discussion-between-ethelene-laverne-and-divakar-gujjala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I did in preventing the form from submitting when there are errors is that I disabled the submit button. But it is not working.

When is it checking for errors? It needs to disable the submit button at the same time it is checking for errors. Your code doesn't work because there's no event telling it WHEN to execute. WHEN do you want submit button to be disabled?

Do you want it triggered when the field is validated or when the form is submitted?

You can't really tie it to the submit button unless you want to click it first to validate the form fields, and then again to submit validated fields. Then you'll need to figure out how to tell it that it's been validated like by a class, maybe? Only accept inputs that hasClass('valid')?

Answer (score 1):

below are the changes

```
$(".form-group").find("td").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('has-error')) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else { 
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not working, Yo. as for the `td` in my `$("td .form-group").each(function() {`, I put my fields inside a table `td`

Comment: It is till not working. :( But I have to tell you that my code `$("td .form-group").each(function() { ... });` works when I pasted it directly on my browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var error = false;
    $("td .form-group").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('has-error') == true) {
            error = true;
            return false; //break out of .each                
        }
    });
    return !error;
});
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by maintaining 2 sections.

**1. Form section**

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

**2. Confirm section**

```
<div id="disp_data" style="display: none;">
  <lable>Name: <span id="name_val"></span></lable>
  <lable>Email: <span id="email_val"></span></lable>
  <input type="button" id="return" value="Return" />
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

You have to submit the form by using js submit method on validating the form in confirm section (When the user clicks on submit button)

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var error_cnt = false;
    if($("#name").val() == '') {
      error_cnt = true;
        alert("Enter Name");      
    }

    if($("#email").val() == '') {
      error_cnt = true;
        alert("Enter Email");
    }

   if(error_cnt == false) {
        $("#form1").submit();
   } else {
    $("#disp_data").hide();
    $("#form1").show();
   }
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLs6snL3/)

Comment: What I mean when there are errors on the form fields is not just the fields are empty, but also when the field values are, for example, not following specific rules like confirm password field should be equal to password field. Whenever that specific error comes out on the confirm password field, the Submit button should get disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the form from sumition by return back a boolean false so that it will stop the execution.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){    

 var ret = (($('#profile-company_name').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-mail_address').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-confirmemail').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-login_name').val().length !=0) && (($('#account-password').val().length !=0)) && ($('#account-confirmpassword').val().length !=0));
 if(!ret) return false;

});
```

If you want to disable the submit button in case of any error you need to monitor the changes of each input fields. so better to give a class name to all those input fields like `commonClass`

then

```
function validation_check(){

 var ret = (($('#profile-company_name').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-mail_address').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-confirmemail').val().length !=0) && ($('#account-login_name').val().length !=0) && (($('#account-password').val().length !=0)) && ($('#account-confirmpassword').val().length !=0));
 return ret;

}

$("#submit").prop("disabled",true)

$(".commonClass").change(function(){
    if(validation_check()){
      $("#submit").prop("disabled",false)
    }
    else {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled",true)
    }
});
```

Comment: Regarding the `commonClass`, that's what I was doing, but since I am using bootstrap for my form, as I inspect element, each field would look like this `<div class="form-group field-account-password required has-error"><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="password" id="account-password" class="form-control" name="Account[password]"></div><div class="col-lg-5"></div><div class="col-lg-6"><p class="help-block help-block-error">Password should contain at least 6 characters.</p></div>
</div>` as you can see it is surrounded by `div`s and the actual `input` field doesn't change if it has errors.

Comment: The only element that changes class is that outside div's class, where it changes from `has-success` to `has-error` classes when the `div` containing the `input` tag that has error

Comment: @EtheleneLaverne `<input type="password" id="account-password" class="form-control commonClass" name="Account[password]">` is this not triggering the change event when using `$(".commonClass").change(function(){...}`

Comment: I hope you could really help me out here.

Comment: @EtheleneLaverne what is your present problem..?? submit button is not disabled..?? also i want to know by chaning the values does it invoke the change function..??

Comment: Can you join in out chat conversation here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102201/discussion-between-ethelene-laverne-and-divakar-gujjala .. I pasted my code there, for clearer understanding.

Answer (score 1):

please use onsubmit attribute in the form element and write a javascript function to return false when there is any error. I've added fiddle you can try.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="" method="" onsubmit="return dosubmit();">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function dosubmit() {
    if(false) { //Check for errors, if there are errors return false. This will prevent th form being submitted.

    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.